# chrome crashed on chromebook (android). How to recover tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, history, chromebook

I was looking for something over google search page, nothing so far besides the classical 'check your history and open the tabs', the issue I had is that chromebook updated and asked if it can restore apps, I chose restore, usually it will open chrome along with the tabs that were opened from last usage. But this time it opened chrome on a new tab, the problem is that even the history doesn't have the record of the two windows being open when it was closed.

Is there any sort of solution to recover those tabs?

Comment: Based on what you described the session data is lost

Comment: You mean there is nothing to do to recover that?

Comment: If I were to guess the data was either never written to disk or overwritten with the new session data.

Comment: This make me wonder what are those developers at google even working on?